# Variable auto completion not working in Eclipse with Pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, autocomplete, pydev

- Windows: Windows 7 Professional
- Python: python-3.6.1-amd64.exe
- pyodbc: pyodbc-4.0.16-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
- Eclipse: Neon.3Release(4.6.3) Build id: 20170314-1500
- PyDev for Eclipse: 5.7.0201704111357

---

After I installed pyodbc by run `pip install pyodbc-4.0.16-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`, I got unresolved import pyodbc in Eclipse. So I manually added "pyodbc" under Python Interpreter > Forced Builtins and "unresolved import pyodbc" issue solved in Eclipse.

However, auto completion does not work for variable in Eclipse with Pydev. I can get auto completion for `pyodbc.connect` but not `conn.cursor()` unless I define `conn = pyodbc.Connection`.

Auto completion not working for variable `conn`

```
import pyodbc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Connecting String....')
    cur = conn.Cursor()
```

Auto completion works for variable `conn`

```
import pyodbc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = pyodbc.Connection
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Connecting String....')
    cur = conn.Cursor()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly because PyDev can't infer what pyodbc.connect returns (it can't really execute that, it can only see that it's a method call and try to guess from its docstring).

You can help it though by adding type hints in docstrings as:

```
#: :type conn: pyodbc.Connection
```

See: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_type_hints.html for more info